# How should I extend standard functionality, like string functions in C?

Tags: c, header

If I am writing my own string functions, the first instinct is to create a string.h header to contain the prototypes for those functions. Of course, there is already a string.h file which is part of the standard set of libraries in C. This library has functions like strcat and strlen, etc.

If I am adding my own string handling functions, essentially extending what is already in the standard libraries, what is the right way to do that? Should I just create mystring.h and include string.h in it, or keep my stuff completely separate from the existing string.h? If I don't want to use string.h can I just implement my own string.h, or is that a bad idea?

Note that I not re-writing strcat, I writing different functions that would ADDITIONAL to the existing ones, not replacements for them.

Comment: The same way you write any library. Include whatever you need from the standard library. It has nothing to do with the specifics of what this library is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a new set of functions, then you'll need to create your own header file with the declarations of those functions.

If on the other hand you're *replacing* some existing string functions, i.e. the names and parameters are the same, then you don't need your own header as the system header will work for those functions.  And since the standard library functions are *weak symbols*, you can link these replacement functions normally and they will override the system functions.

Comment: Pretty sure having functions with the names of standard library functions is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: @EOF  It is not UB.  I would not recommend it either.